# What is the input for the interpret of Quantum Variational Regressors?

Tags: programming, qiskit, vqe, quantum-neural-network

I'm trying to implement my first variational regressor using qiskit. I would like to understand how the interpret of a CircuitQNN works.
I need to define an interpret that works on the amplitudes of a certain set of measured basis states. Considering this I'm trying to get the counts obtained by executing the circuit for S shots and then perform some operations using these values to finally obtain the output of my regressor.

I saw the Qiskit's tutorial example (https://qiskit.org/documentation/machine-learning/tutorials/02_neural_network_classifier_and_regressor.html#Regression) in which they use the parity to get the class of an instance. But, I think they compute the parity for the bitstring measured at each shot, here I would like to execute all the S shots and then on the counts perform some operations.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.